# The system cannot find the file specified in Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

I checked lots of reference site to solve this problem but no one giving correct solution. I hosted my application on windows server 2008/2012 then it's not working.

Actually it's working fine on local system but after publishing, i am hosting this application on server then it's not working.

Below are errors details.

> > The system cannot find the file specified.
> >
> > Description: An unhandled exception `enter code here` occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
> >
> > Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
> >
> > Source Error:
> >          An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

```
Stack Trace:

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)
  +5296071    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
  stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +558

  System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,
  SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
  Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean
  integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +5308555

  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
  serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
  Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
  withFailover) +145

  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
  serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
  Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
  SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +920

  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
  timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
  credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
  Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307

  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
  identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
  credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
  newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
  userConnectionOptions) +434

  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
  options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
  DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
  DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +225

  System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
  pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey,
  DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +37

  System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions
  userOptions) +558

  System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions
  userOptions) +67

  System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
  owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
  allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
  userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1052

  System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
  owningObject, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
  userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +167

  System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
  outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
  TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +143
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource1
  retry) +83    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96

  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(SqlConnection
  sqlConnection, Action1 act) +79.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +384.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +241
System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +26

[ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.]
System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +170
System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.GetStorageMetadata(String providerName, DbConnection connection, String ssdl) +35
System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateMetadataWorkspace(String providerName, DbConnection connection, String csdl, String ssdl, String msl) +154
System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateEntityConnection(ConnectionStringSettings setting, String csdl, String ssdl, String msl) +109
System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateMembershipEntities(ConnectionStringSettings setting) +28
System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String userName, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& format, String& salt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate) +118
System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String userName, String password, Boolean updateLastActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat) +81
System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +105
System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +26 Staff.Web.Account.Login.OnAuthenticate(Object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e) in c:\Assembla\SVN\servicesdue\Staff.Web\Staff.Web\Account\Login.aspx.cs:28 System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs e) +9449786 System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +119.
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +75 System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +114
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +159.
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.
RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10.
```

Comment: Is your connection string correct?

Answer (score -1):

As you can see in stack trace. Its telling you the problem. Most probably, Your connection to database is down or you are unable to connect database server.

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database
>   Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly
>   installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]"

Further you need to look into:

1] `Firewall settings` from the web server to the database server
2] Connection string errors
3] Enable the appropriate protocol pipes/ tcp-ip
4] Check `SQL Server service` running or not

Comment: I already try this thing and checked. Please give other solution for that because after applying this thing it's not resolving this error.

Comment: Do you see this in stack trace. It's all about your DB connection string. **"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]"**